# pg_hba.conf - client side fatal error

Tags: postgresql

I have a user who gets:

> FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "2002:8c64:7831::8c64:7831" user
>   "", database "postgis", SSL Off

when trying to retrieve data from Postgres using QGIS 2.0.  The user has had a new machine (running 32bit Windows 7).  The rest of the estate are currently running XP, and no-one else ius reporting the issue.  My pg_hba.conf has all as trusted:

```
host    all all 127.0.0.1/32    trust
host    all all 0.0.0.0/0   trust 
host    all all ::1/128     trust 
host    all all 0.0.0.0/0   trust
```

Do I need to make any changes to the pg_hba.conf file for a windows 7 client? or what changes do I need to make to get it working?

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault, but pro-tip is that you are missing allow entries for ipv6, you only allow localhost over ipv6. You should add ::/0 (all addresses) or 2000::/3 (all routable addresses) as well.

Comment: @jishi - thanks, have added the record to pg_hba.conf and am awaiting user to test

Comment: @jishi - your suggestion worked, thanks - do you want to offer it up as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: yeah, I guess I should do that. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing allow entries for ipv6, you only allow localhost over ipv6. You should add ::/0 (all addresses) or 2000::/3 (all routable addresses) as well.